# CSV to LIBSVM converter

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

I am trying to learn bit of machine learning with LibSVM. I have some testing data in a Excel CSV format "testingset.csv" file but i have to convert this data set to be able to work in LibSVM. I have the following code but cannot seem to convert it :

```
import sys
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def construct_line( label, line ):
    new_line = []
    if float( label ) == 0.0:
        label = "0"
    new_line.append( label )

    for i, item in enumerate( line ):
        if item == '' or float( item ) == 0.0:
            continue
        new_item = "%s:%s" % ( i + 1, item )
        new_line.append( new_item )
    new_line = " ".join( new_line )
    new_line += "\n"
    return new_line

# ---

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

try:
    label_index = int( sys.argv[3] )
except IndexError:
    label_index = 0

try:
    skip_headers = sys.argv[4]
except IndexError:
    skip_headers = 0

i = open( input_file, 'rb' )
o = open( output_file, 'wb' )

reader = csv.reader( i )

if skip_headers:
    headers = reader.next()

for line in reader:
    if label_index == -1:
        label = '1'
    else:
        label = line.pop( label_index )

    new_line = construct_line( label, line )
    o.write( new_line )
```

Comment: Can you show us your data file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code are redundant
The format of svm input file is

```
l 1:x 2:y 3:z 4:...
l 1:x 2:y 3:z 4:...
```

where l is the label

I think you can prepare the input file as txt file seperated by \t (save the file as txt with excel)

```
    A   B   C   D
1   l   x   y   z
2   l   x   y   z
...
```

than use the code

```
import sys
f=[i.split() for i in open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
open(sys.argv[1]+'_4libsvm','w').writelines([i[0]+" "+" ".join(pstr(k+1)+":"+j for k,j in enumerate(i[1:])])+"\n" for i in f])
```

then execute
python pythonfile.py input1.txt input2.txt ... 
it will convert all the inputfile